# simple_form & Bootstrap styles not being applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have started using simple_form in my app since I have been using bootstrap i wanted to connect the two.

I installed the gem and ran `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`

In my form file I have this

```
<%= simple_form_for(@provider, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

but none of the bootstrap styles are being applied. It just showing the basic elements.

I followed this example http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/documentation to make sure I was doing it right.

I have the `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'` installed and inside my application.css.scss I have this line `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
      @import "bootstrap";`

Can anyone recommend another approach? Or point out where I am going wrong.

Much appreciated.

Damien

Comment: did you restart the server after installing the gem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look through the github issues and found that a few people had issues not specifying the gem version. I simply did this:

```
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0.rc1', github: 'plataformatec/simple_form'
```

and then re-ran the install generator and all worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you read this [doc](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Twitter-Bootstrap-v2-and-simple_form-v2)? I'm not sure if that helps you this? But when I worked with Twitter Bootstrap + Simple Form I had to describe wrapers for this. And check [this guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Twitter-Bootstrap-integration)